# unistrut channel on wood post

Tags: mounting

I am mounting my meter/distribution panel & RV panel on a 6x6 post (opposite sides). I was thinking about mounting Unistrut channel to the post for better support across the back of my main panel and to allow me to shift it to one side so i can line up my back knockout with the back knockout on my RV panel which will be mounted on the other side of the post.
Now I know I can just bolt the panel directly to the post and just off set it to one side to achieve the same result, but I thought the channel would also provide more support and the little screws coming out the back of the panel would not be digging into the wood. Am I over thinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use strut get the 1/4-20 strut nuts and they will hold the panel to the strut with no problems, make sure to lag the strut in place. I use strut regularly for mounting when the box(s) or disconnect(s) need spacing or proper support.

Make sure to debur the edges if you cut it or you can end up getting a nasty cut putting the nuts in the channel.

Comment: i got the 1/4-20 bolts and lock washers since the nuts are not self locking. Not sure what would keep them tighten.

Comment: Dean I work in a lumber mill with high vibration and I use exactly what you have yes on some equipment things can loosen but do you expect your house th be constantly shacking? I have never had a problem with commercial or residential, just occasionally with heavy industrial if you want you can add some lock tight thread locker but you do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use structural screws and add fender washers if I was worried abut the screws pulling through the back of the panel.

It all depends on what size of gorilla you want to be prepared for.

alternatively you can use a hole-saw nibbler, chassis punch, dremel, offset snips, etc to make a hole where you want it (so long as it doesn't foul the equipment in the box), the knock-outs are a convenience, not a requirement.

Comment: Ya I hear you. I think I will just use some nice screws and big washers as you suggest. That was my original plan and got off on this idea. I think i can make the existing knockouts work using a meter offset terminal fitting on one end. Thanks for the advise.